# How can I get the concatenation of string in an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code using Python:

```
a = [["Hello", "cat", "dog"], ["Hello", "food", "fish"],
["Good Bye", "English", "words"], ["Good Bye", "England", "word"],
["Good Bye", "Islands", "Country"]]
```

And I would like to create an array using a like this:

```
b = [["Hello", "cat food", "dog fish"],
["Good Bye", "English England Islands",
"words word Country"]]
```

Do you know how can I do this?

Comment: Your example is not concatenation string with array...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `groupby` to group all lists beginning with the same word, `zip` to iterate over all items within the same group and then remove duplicates when there are more than one occurrence of the same word

```
>>> a = [["Hello", "cat", "dog"], ["Hello", "food", "fish"],
... ["Good Bye", "English", "words"], ["Good Bye", "England", "word"],
... ["Good Bye", "Islands", "Country"]]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> b = [[' '.join(list(dict.fromkeys(item))) for item in zip(*grp)] for _,grp in groupby(a, key=lambda l: l[0])]
>>> print(*b, sep='\n')
['Hello', 'cat food', 'dog fish']
['Good Bye', 'English England Islands', 'words word Country']
```

Comment: Thank you what is the library to use groupby ?

Comment: itertools, it's built-in

Comment: Sorry. Updated the answer. It is from `itertools`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
a = [["Hello", "cat", "dog"], ["Hello", "food", "fish"],
 ["Good Bye", "English", "words"], ["Good Bye", "England", "word"],
 ["Good Bye", "Islands", "Country"]]
an = []
for i in set(_[0] for _ in a):
    t = [_ for _ in a if i==_[0]]
    m = [' '.join(_) for _ in zip(*t) if not _[0]==i]
    an.append([t[0][0]]+m)
```

**Output** :

```
# an becomes
[['Hello', 'cat food', 'dog fish'], ['Good Bye', 'English England Islands', 'words word Country']]
```